# Lotus Notes and IE Issue "document.all("RunAgentCreateAns").click() does not work in IE11"

Tags: javascript, lotus-notes, internet-explorer-11

I'm supporting a old Lotus Notes Application which is used in IE Browser
Every thing was fine until few users start using IE11.

JS code which is not working

```
document.all("RunAgentCreateAns").click()
```

**RunAgentCreateAns** is Button ID in Lotus Notes.

same code is working in IE9 and IE8. No Idea why it is not working in IE11

Answer (score 5):

IE11 does not support `document.all()`. Use `document.getElementById()` instead. See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537434(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537434%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Although MS docs clearly state they do not support document.all anymore, some programmatic testing shows IE11 "quietly" still *does* support document.all, apparently.

In IE11, `document.all` by itself, as would be used in proper feature testing, is 'falsy', meaning it would fail a feature presence test - as any non-supported feature should. However, if you *directly use it*, eg document.all('fieldname'), you'll still get a reference to a element with an ID of 'fieldname.'

Consider the following HTML snippet, which was tested on IE11 Version 11.0.9600.17041:

```
<html>
<script language="javascript">
   function testDA(){
      if (document.all){
         alert('Yes: ' + document.all['foo'].value);
      } else {
         alert('No: But...' + document.all['foo'].value);
      }

      var x = document.all['payday'];
      x.click();

      var y = document.all('payday');
      y.click();

      document.all('payday').click();
  }

  function clicked(){
      alert('clicked.');
  }
</script>
<form>
  <button onclick='testDA()'>Button 1</button>
  <button id='payday' onclick='clicked()'>Button 2</button>
  <input type='text' id='foo' value='I am not here.'>
</form>
</html>
```

Load this page into IE11, and click 'Button 1', and you'll see an alert dialog pop up saying 'No: But...I am not here.'. That shows `document.all` in the `if` is returning false, tripping to the else. Yet the reference through that property obviously works.

Note that the button labeled `Button 2` and having an id of 'payday' has an `onclick` handler defined, and it is programmatically referenced in the `testDA` function through `document.all` via an array reference and a function call reference, and a direct reference in the way the OP posted here. In this test case, all three work - in each case, the click function defined for the button fires.

It would seem this "feature" is intentional presumably (?) for compatibility purposes, but given MS' docs explicit statement that it "has been removed," suggests to me it could disappear at the whim of a KB patch or OS service pack. Caveat jscriptor.